# How to use cv2.resize (v4.2.0)

Tags: python, opencv

I’m confused, please help me understand:

I have this error:

```
    img_array = cv2.resize(img_array, dsize=(299, 299, 3), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)                                                                                                              
TypeError: function takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

When

```
print(img_array): <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
img_array.shape: (240, 320, 3)
print(cv2.__version__): 4.2.0
```

Mouseover on resize in VSCode shows

```
def resize(src, dsize, dst=None, fx=None, fy=None, interpolation=None)
resize(src, dsize[, dst[, fx[, fy[, interpolation]]]]) -> dst . @brief Resizes an image. .
. The function resize resizes the image src down to or up to the specified size. Note that the . initial dst type or size are not taken into account. Instead, the size and type are derived from . the src,dsize,fx, and fy. If you want to resize src so that it fits the pre-created dst, . you may call the function as follows: . @code . // explicitly specify dsize=dst.size(); fx and fy will be computed from that. . resize(src, dst, dst.size(), 0, 0, interpolation); . @endcode . If you want to decimate the image by factor of 2 in each direction, you can call the function this . way: . @code . // specify fx and fy and let the function compute the destination image size. . resize(src, dst, Size(), 0.5, 0.5, interpolation); . @endcode . To shrink an image, it will generally look best with #INTER_AREA interpolation, whereas to . enlarge an image, it will generally look best with c#INTER_CUBIC (slow) or #INTER_LINEAR . (faster but still looks OK). .
. @param src input image. . @param dst output image; it has the size dsize (when it is non-zero) or the size computed from . src.size(), fx, and fy; the type of dst is the same as of src. . @param dsize output image size; if it equals zero, it is computed as: . \f[\texttt{dsize = Size(round(fx*src.cols), round(fy*src.rows))}\f] . Either dsize or both fx and fy must be non-zero. . @param fx scale factor along the horizontal axis; when it equals 0, it is computed as . \f[\texttt{(double)dsize.width/src.cols}\f] . @param fy scale factor along the vertical axis; when it equals 0, it is computed as . \f[\texttt{(double)dsize.height/src.rows}\f] . @param interpolation interpolation method, see #InterpolationFlags .
. @sa warpAffine, warpPerspective, remap
```

Which is inconsistent with what is in the docs https://docs.opencv.org/4.2.0/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga47a974309e9102f5f08231edc7e7529d

Does anyone know what’s up? **How do I correctly use cv2.resize v4.2.0? (since all my googling yielded the code I attempted to run)**

Comment: I believe the dsize is just the width and height. `dsize=(299, 299)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the error comes from the dimension that requires only the width and height.

Try this:

```
img_array = cv2.resize(img_array, dsize=(299, 299), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
```

You can find the detailed explanation here:

[Explanation  of cv2.resize](https://www.tutorialkart.com/opencv/python/opencv-python-resize-image/)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, that was it. It's still mind boggling how the comments in the code don't match with what's in the documentation (isn't the documentation auto generated from the code?), but oh well

Comment: I guess (not sure, just guess), in the statement "TypeError: function takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given) ", the function refers to "dtype". "dtype" probably refers to an internal function or object. But I agree, this message is a bit misleading...

Answer (score 1):

I would go about this by doing:

```
new_img_array = cv2.resize("img_array", dsize=(299,229))
```

I don't believe that interpolation is necessary for simple resizing.